# Timing single operation to not be repeated for a fixed time

Tags: java, multithreading

Sometimes "a" service does not respond and so we need to restart it. Usually it's a glitch in the network. We can have like 100 calls at the same time so the service cannot be restarted for 100 hundred times. The service is a Singleton. The command is called through a dispatcher, it's sync so different calls are executed in sequence.

Do you think that this approach is right to limit the restarting of the service?

```
public class RecoverServiceCommand extends AbstractCommand {
    /**
     * Logger for this class
     */
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(RecoverServiceCommand.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isAsynch() {
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean postCondition(Object... arg0) {
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preCondition(Object... arg0) {
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void undo() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doExecute(Object... arg0) throws CommandException {
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    synchronized (RecoverServiceCommand.class) {
        if (now - Service.getInstance().getLastUpdate() > Utils.TimeSpan)
        Service.getInstance().restartService(now);
        else
        log.warn("Messaging queues not restarted because it was already restarted not so long ago");
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, it looks like as a workaround for another bug. You might want to fix that bug instead of this workaround.
2. Comments like the following are unnecessary:

   ```
    /**
    * Logger for this class
    */
   ```

   It just repeats the code and forces readers to read more than necessary.
3. `Service.getInstance()` is repeated. Create a local variable for it.
4. Synchronizing on public objects (like `RecoverServiceCommand.class`) is error-prone.  I'd use a private lock object instead. See: [Avoid synchronized(this) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/442564/843804)
5. A minor change could be extracting out a `boolean needsRestart` local variable which would make the intention of the expression a little bit more clear.

   Reference: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods*, *Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler

   > Put the result of the expression, or parts of the expression, 
   >   in a temporary variable with a name that explains the purpose.
6. Currently the code is tightly coupled with the `Service` and the `Utils` classes. If you want to write unit tests it's not too easy because it needs a working `Service` instance and it depends on the system time too. To make it easier to test you could pass the dependencies to the constructor:

   ```
   private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

   private final Service service;

   private final Ticker ticker;

   private final long updateInterval;

   public RecoverServiceCommand(final Service service, final Ticker ticker, 
           final long updateInterval) {
       this.service = checkNotNull(service);
       this.ticker = checkNotNull(ticker);
       checkArgument(updateInterval > 0, "updateIntarval must be bigger than zero");
       this.updateInterval = updateInterval;
   }

   @Override
   protected void doExecute(final Object... arg0) throws CommandException {
       final long now = ticker.read();
       lock.lock();
       try {
           final boolean needsRestart = 
               (now - service.getLastUpdate()) > updateInterval;
           if (needsRestart) {
               service.restartService(now);
           } else {
               log.warn("Messaging queues not restarted because "
                   + "it was already restarted not so long ago");
           }
       } finally {
           lock.unlock();
       }
   }
   ```

   Here is a few tests with EasyMock:

   ```
   import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;

   import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;
   import org.junit.After;
   import org.junit.Before;
   import org.junit.Test;

   import com.google.common.base.Ticker;

   public class RecoverServiceCommandTest {

       private EasyMockSupport mockery;
       private Service service;
       private Ticker ticker;

       @Before
       public void setUp() {
           mockery = new EasyMockSupport();
           service = mockery.createMock(Service.class);
           ticker = mockery.createMock(Ticker.class);
       }

       @After
       public void tearDown() {
           mockery.verifyAll();

       }

       @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
       public void testInvalidUpdateInterval() throws Exception {
           final long invalidUpdateInterval = 0;

           mockery.replayAll();

           new RecoverServiceCommand(service, ticker, invalidUpdateInterval);
       }

       @Test
       public void testUpdateIsRequired() throws Exception {
           final long updateInterval = 100;

           final long currentTime = 300L;
           expect(ticker.read()).andReturn(currentTime);
           expect(service.getLastUpdate()).andReturn(199L);
           service.restartService(currentTime);

           mockery.replayAll();

           final RecoverServiceCommand command = 
               new RecoverServiceCommand(service, ticker, updateInterval);
           command.doExecute();
       }

       @Test
       public void testUpdateIsNotRequired() throws Exception {
           final long updateInterval = 100;

           final long currentTime = 300L;
           expect(ticker.read()).andReturn(currentTime);
           expect(service.getLastUpdate()).andReturn(200L);

           mockery.replayAll();

           final RecoverServiceCommand command = 
               new RecoverServiceCommand(service, ticker, updateInterval);
           command.doExecute();
       }

   }
   ```

   I've used the [`Ticker class`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Ticker.html) from Guava. It's easy to mock it and it has a [`systemTicker`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Ticker.html#systemTicker%28%29) which you can use in production code. The [check methods are also in Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html).

Comment: 1. Yes, working on that :)
2. It's the log4E plugin
4. Didn't know that, thanks!
6. It's not the way the dispatcher works but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.